# Get Auth0 access_token from existing id_token

Tags: javascript, oauth, jwt, auth0

I'm using [auth0](http://auth0.com) to authenticate my logins to my Single Page App (built on React). I'm mostly using the base API calls (listed [here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication)).

The process I'm using is:

get username/email and password when the user enters them on my app's login page
Send a POST request to `/oauth/ro` with those values - here is that code:

```
export const login = (params, err) => {
  if (err) return err
  const {email, password} = params
  const {AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_DOMAIN} = process.env
  return fetch(`${AUTH0_DOMAIN}/oauth/ro`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'client_id': AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      'username': email,
      'password': password,
      'connection': 'Username-Password-Authentication',
      'grant_type': 'password',
      'scope': 'openid',
      'device': '',
      'id_token': ''
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const {id_token, access_token} = json
    setCookieValue('id_token', id_token) // utility function I wrote
    return getProfile(access_token)
      .then(data => {
        const {user_id, email: emailAddress, picture, name} = data
        return {id_token, user_id, emailAddress, picture, name}
      })
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`))
}
```

This is all sent through Redux and the user is logged in (assuming the username/password was correct).

However, I'm trying to figure out how to persist the login when refreshing the page/coming back to the app. I'm saving the `id_token` (which is a [JWT](http://jwt.io)) in the browser's cookies and can fetch this when the app renders server-side. I can decode the JWT and get the payload (`sub` is the user ID from auth0). However, to get the profile data I need the `access_token` which Auth0 provides when using the `/oauth/ro` POST request. Obviously, if the JWT token has expired then it will just reject it and keep the user logged out.

Here is my code to decode the JWT (happens on app render):

```
const ID_TOKEN = req.cookies.id_token || false
if (ID_TOKEN) {
  verifyJwt(ID_TOKEN, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) { console.log(`JWT Verification error: ${err}`) }
    else {
      const {sub} = decoded
      getProfile(sub).then(data => store.dispatch(fetchUserDetails(data))) // fails as `sub` (the user id) is not the `access_token` which it requires
    }
  })
}
```

I have tried using the `/oauth/ro` call again, but this time specifying `"grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"` and using the `id_token` retrieved from the cookies, and specifying a `device`. However, when I do this call, I get this error from Auth0:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "there is not an associated public key for specified client_id/user_id/device"
}
```

So my question is, what API call do I need to make to get the `access_token` from the `id_token` JWT?

Also, as a bonus - when I do the POST request to login, the `password` is being transfered over plaintext. How would I encrypt this when sending to auth0 so they can decrypt it back? I assume it involves using the `client_secret` which auth0 provide but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to refresh a token programmatically without any type of user interaction is accomplished through the use of [refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token). However, this is not applicable for browser-based applications because refresh tokens are long-lived credentials and the storage characteristics for browsers would place them at a too bigger risk of being leaked.

If you want to continue to use the resource owner password credentials grant you can choose to ask the user to input the credentials again when the tokens expire. As an alternative, upon authentication you can obtain the required user information and initiate an application specific session. This could be achieved by having your server-side logic create an application specific session identifier or JWT.

You can also stop using the resource owner password credentials grant and redirect the user to an Auth0 authentication page that besides returning the tokens to your application would also maintain an authenticated session for the user, meaning that when the tokens expired and your application redirected again to Auth0, the user might not need to manual reenter credentials because the Auth0 session is still valid.

In relation to the password being sent in plaintext; the resource owner endpoint relies on HTTPS so the data is encrypted at the protocol level. You must also use HTTPS within your own application for any type of communication that includes user credentials of any kind.

Also note that you can control what's returned within the ID token through the use of scopes, depending on the amount of information in question you might not even need to make additional calls to get the user profiles if you [signal that you want that information to be contained within the ID token itself](https://auth0.com/docs/scopes#requesting-specific-claims).

Comment: Hi Joao, thanks for your detailed answer. I've read about refresh tokens and how they shouldn't be stored in the browser as they are long lasting and present a security hole if they get into the wrong hands. However, I'm not which API call I need to use to get the `refresh_token` from auth0 (I don't really want to redirect my user to an Auth0 login page like for `/authorize`). I might just leave it for now - it's only an MVP so if the user needs to re-login each time that's alright. Thanks!

Comment: Given that you understand the consequences I don't feel as bad for showing you how to do it... :) You can obtain refresh tokens through the resource owner endpoint by including `offline_access` as a scope and then additionally passing a `device` parameter with an arbitrary value. The link I posted shows how to do this with another endpoint, but you apply it also the `ro` one.

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you! When I tried this with `/oauth/ro`, (arbitrary `device` value) it gave me the error above (`"error_description": "there is not an associated public key for specified client_id/user_id/device"`). I was including the `id_token` and had changed the `grant_type` (to the string above in the question). How would I fix this error?

Comment: You need to do the steps I mentioned when calling `ro` with the username/password and the `password` grant type. The response will then also include a refresh tokens besides the other tokens you were obtaining.